# Where can I find documentation about interacting with bitcoind's json-rpc?

Tags: wallet, json-rpc

I have created a coin by forking Bitcoin. Now I want to create web wallet for this, but do not know how to create json-rpc apis to communicate with the daemon server.
Is there any proper documentation for this?

Answer (score 1):

Visit [API reference (JSON-RPC)](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC))

There are several solutions:

1. You can **build bitcoin-cli** (which provides json-rpc communication with deamon through command line), and **call bash commands on the server**. *For example, if You run PHP server, You can [asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42224107/php-execute-shell-command-asynchronously-and-retrieve-live-output) run bash commands.*
2. Also You can use **json-rpc libraries** on your server - feel free to google for them. *For example, if You run PHP server, You can use a library like [php-bitcoin-api](https://github.com/phramz/php-bitcoin-api).*
3. Also, I recommend You to run own **blockchain explorer** which will help You to communicate with a blockchain of Your coin. *For example, try to run [bitcoin-abe](https://github.com/bitcoin-abe/bitcoin-abe) explorer or any other.*

Hope it will be helpful!

Comment: bitcoin wallet only allows one user for a single node, i am not getting how to enable my node so that anybody having privete key and address can connect and do transactions through my node.

Comment: is there any javascript library like web3 .js for ethereum in bitcoin so that we can do transaction directlly without connecting with any wallet.

Comment: In my opinion, the easiest way is to: 1) Use explorer to check balances and to get inputs and outputs of transactions 2) Use bitcoin-js-lib to generate new addresses, to build and sign transactions 3) Use command line on your server to broadcast transactions to the network (bitcoin-cli sendrawtransaction <hex>)

Answer (score 0):

## The interface

There is a doc on the [JSON-RPC Interface](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/5574e489631bb20c4566df916b79863f31dc6f0c/doc/JSON-RPC-interface.md) in the Bitcoin Core repository with some important security information.

## Individual commands

```
bitcoin-cli [options] help                List commands
bitcoin-cli [options] help <command>      Get help for a command
```

This same information is also available at https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/

These docs were added as part of the Bitcoin Core release process at least in part by this PR: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/d6189ff20082a2617f843fa9b8e2635f52a3629a